# Correct arabic chapter-section numbering with Endfloat

Tags: floats, numbering, endfloat

The first table in the second chapter of this MWE is marked as 'Table 2.2 About here'. The chapter-section numbering is not set up correctly, as Endfloat usually just numbers the tables sequentially throughout the whole document. How do I ensure the first table in Chapter two is listed as 'Table 2.1 About here'?

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[tablesfirst,notablist]{endfloat}
\usepackage{titletoc}

\renewcommand\theposttable{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{posttbl}}
\renewcommand\thepostfigure{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{postfig}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Data}
\startlist{lot}
\begin{table}
\caption{Data chapter table}
\begin{tabular}{c}
123 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\printlist{lot}{}{\chapter*{List of tables in Chapter~\thechapter}}
\processdelayedfloats

\chapter{Learning}
\startlist{lot}
\begin{table}
\caption{Learning chapter table}
\begin{tabular}{c}
123 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\printlist{lot}{}{\chapter*{List of tables in Chapter~\thechapter}}
\processdelayedfloats

\end{document}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You can use `chngcntr` package and reset counters per chapter. Also note that the counters `posttbl` and `postfig` have been replaced by `posttable and`postfigure' from version 2.5. From manual:

[image]

```
\documentclass[oneside,12pt]{book}
\usepackage[tablesfirst,notablist]{endfloat}
\usepackage{titletoc}
\usepackage{chngcntr}                   %% <-- new
\counterwithin{posttable}{chapter}      %% <-- new
\counterwithin{postfigure}{chapter}     %% <-- new 

\renewcommand\theposttable{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{posttable}}
\renewcommand\thepostfigure{\arabic{chapter}.\arabic{postfigure}}

\begin{document}
\chapter{Data}
\startlist{lot}
\begin{table}
\caption{Data chapter table}
\begin{tabular}{c}
123 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\printlist{lot}{}{\chapter*{List of tables in Chapter~\thechapter}}
\processdelayedfloats

\chapter{Learning}
\startlist{lot}
\begin{table}
\caption{Learning chapter table}
\begin{tabular}{c}
123 \\
\end{tabular}
\end{table}

\printlist{lot}{}{\chapter*{List of tables in Chapter~\thechapter}}
\processdelayedfloats

\end{document}
```

[image]